# unable to call build.xml from java main method

Tags: java, xml, ant

I want to call build.xml from Java. To do so, I mentioned below code in Java main method:

```
Process process;
        try {
                process = new ProcessBuilder("ant","-f" ,"D:/Selenium/Workspace/test_project/build.xml").start();
                process.waitFor();
                InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

                } catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

But am getting error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ant": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.gui.test.TestClass_Base.main(TestClass_Base.java:155)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems `ant` is not on your path. So it doesn't find it.

Or... it does not find this file:

`D:/Selenium/Workspace/test_project/build.xml`

I am not quite sure. Check both, see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The entry point for Ant on Windows is a batch script, `ant.bat`. Batch scripts have to run in a command interpreter such as `cmd.exe`.

Try this:

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/c","ant","-f","D:/Selenium/Workspace/test_project/build.xml")
```